# Encrypt binary file with xor Jscript WSH

Tags: encryption, xor, jscript, wsh

When encrypting string using xor encryption, things work well. But when dealing with bytes, it does not work for. It throws error at `k.charCodeAt(0)` Please what could be the problem? This is my full code.

```
function Main() {
var key;

key = "thisistheencryptionkey";

WScript.Echo("Encryption started . . .");
Crypt( "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\file.exe", "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\fileenc.txt", key );
WScript.Echo("Decryption started . . .");
Crypt( "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\fileenc.txt", "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\file.exe", key );
WScript.Echo("Finished!");}

function Crypt(fileIn, fileOut, key) {
var fileInRead, objFSOFile;
objFSOFile = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
var e = objFSOFile.getFile(fileIn);
var fileSize = e.size;
key = key;
while (key.length < fileSize) {
    key += key;
}

var adTypeBinaryWrite = 1;
var adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2;
var BinaryStreamWrite;
BinaryStreamWrite = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
BinaryStreamWrite.Type = adTypeBinaryWrite;
BinaryStreamWrite.Open();


var adTypeBinary = 1;
var BinaryStream;
BinaryStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary;
BinaryStream.Open();
BinaryStream.LoadFromFile(fileIn);

var k, ss, q;
i = 0;
do {
    q = key.substr(i, 1);
    k = BinaryStream.Read(1);

    ss = q.charCodeAt(0);
    BinaryStreamWrite.Write(String.fromCharCode(k.charCodeAt(0) ^ ss));
    i = i + 1;
} while (!BinaryStream.EOS);

BinaryStream.close();

BinaryStreamWrite.SaveToFile(fileOut, adSaveCreateOverWrite);
BinaryStreamWrite.close();}
```

EDIT:
Error says: Object expected
ERROR Code: 800A138F

Comment: *It throws error* - what error?

Comment: @Bravo Error says: Object expected ERROR Code: 800A138F

Comment: What line is the error thrown on?

Comment: @user692942 line 44 `BinaryStreamWrite.Write(String.fromCharCode(k.charCodeAt(0) ^ ss));`

Comment: Is it definitely `String.`? JScript is case sensitive and follows camelCase so would expect it to be `string.`. Case is important in JScript unlike VBScript.

Comment: @user692942 error say: "string is undefined". String. seems correct in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a binary file and save it to local file system in WSH (JScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330187/how-can-i-create-a-binary-file-and-save-it-to-local-file-system-in-wsh-jscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out a lot of things that didn't work,this is what worked for me and it's implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336942/16533513

Comment: In which case flag as a duplicate.